# How to resize ImageViews to fit the screen in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, resize-image

So I have seven ImageViews vertically with the first at the top of the screen and the 7th is in the bottom of the screen (2.7inch).

When I install this app on a larger screen (4.7inch), the first image is on the top screen but the 7th is in the middle of the screen I want it to fit perfectly like in the 2.7inch.

I want the image to increase in size automatically but I don't know how to do that.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper_08"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />       

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:layout_height="0px"` and `android:layout_weight=""`.

Apply the following in all ImageViews:

```
android:layout_height="0px"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: thank you but now came out 2 other questions. 1. The images are not increased only the padding increased, how to increase image?. 2. How to do this in a grid view?

Comment: use android_scalType="fitxy".

Comment: I will check this android_scalType out, glad to learn a new function on android.  Thank you

Comment: It's actually  **android:scaleType="fitXY"**

Comment: @ArtooDetoo yeh it's typo as I was not on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You can set all the ImageViews to have a layout_height of **0dp** and a layout_weight of **1**.
This will distribute the vertical space equally

So:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper_08"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes it worked.thank you but now came out 2 other questions. 1. The images are not increased only the padding increased, how to increase image?. 2. How to do this in a grid view?

Comment: 1 - To increase the images... well here is where you would provide a set of proportioned images for each drawable-XYZdpi folders OR (not as good), just make the bigger ones for xxhdpi resolution (480 dpi), put them into drawable-xxhdpi and let Android do the scaling.

Comment: 2 - To put the images in a GridView, refer to this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: yes I used that just like the page, I did it with 4.7inch screen and when I installed the app in a smaller screen the images were all stick together, not so good to see. "proportioned images" -- yeah but I want to use the same image.

Comment: OK, did you do the number 1, as well? This is important. Because the images must scale well. Then using Ketan Ahir suggestion, use **android:scaleType="fitXY"**

Comment: This doesn't work for me using "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout..."

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Well, I guess it doesn't. Because CostraintLayout should be more flexible.